# pytest fails when tested function is Click command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Using Python 3.6.4, Click==7.0, and pytest==4.4.0.
I got into a trouble when using Click & pytest at the same time.

test_foo.py

```
import unittest

import click
import pytest

@click.command()
def foo():
    print(1)


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        foo()
```

And when execute `pytest test_foo.py::TestFoo::test_foo` , it says

```
Usage: pytest [OPTIONS]
Try "pytest --help" for help.

Error: Got unexpected extra argument 
(tests/test_foo.py::TestFoo::test_foo)
```

All of the pytest options (such as `-k` or `-m`) does not work when Click command is enabled to the tested method.

It works fine when I comment out the line of `@click.command()`, of course.

How does everyone solve this when using both of them at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`ClickRunner`](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.testing.CliRunner) to isolate the execution of click commands in tests. Your example, reworked:

```
import unittest
import click
import click.testing


@click.command()
def foo():
    print(1)


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        runner = click.testing.CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(foo)
        assert result.exit_code == 0
        assert result.output == '1\n'
```

Check out the relevant [doc page](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/testing/) for more examples.

Comment: Is there a way to get `ipdb` working using `CliRunner()`? `pytest -s ` does not seem to work.